# PHP Supporting multiple languages in a mail

Tags: php, email, multiple-languages

I have an application in PHP which can receive mails in multiple languages hence different charsets. Once I fetch the mail it should be stored in db in UTF-8 encoding.

For e.g. I recevied a mail in french "Une bonne journée, tout le monde!" charset: ISO-8859-1   or korean "좋은 일, 세계!" charset: EUC-KR. 
Now I am reading the mails using Zend Imap API and then convert it to encoding UTF-8 using iconv($charset,'UTF-8//TRANSLIT',$part). $charset is parsed from the mail and substituted.

But I am still not able to achieve the correct results. Please let me know what would be the solution

Comment: `But I am still not able to achieve the correct results` - What results do you get? In what way are they not correct?

Comment: In the db for french I am only getting "Une bonne journ" and for korean it is empty space. The result should be the complete text

Comment: Sounds like `//TRANSLIT` is not playing the game - [`Otherwise, str is cut from the first illegal character and an E_NOTICE is generated`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) - turn on error reporting (`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - do you see the aforementioned `E_NOTICE`?

Comment: Also, try [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) if it is available

Comment: Since php is reading in ASCII or utf-8 I am first doing "mb_convert_encoding($part,$charset,mb_detect_encoding($part))" and then executing " iconv($charset,'UTF-8//TRANSLIT',$part)"

Comment: You shouldn't need to do both `mb_convert_encoding()` and `iconv()` - one or the other should suffice. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I checked for E_NOTICE I do not see any errors.

Comment: Try just doing `mb_convert_encoding($part, 'utf-8', $encoding)` and using that value without the `iconv()`

Comment: As per my understanding mb_convert_encoding will use the correct encoding and then iconv will change the bits to represent the same characters. Please correct me if I understood it incorrectly

Comment: As far as I understand it `mb_convert_encoding()` will convert to the correct encoding - which effectively *does* convert it to the correct binary sequences. Since the destination charset is UTF-8, and there aren't really any characters in common usage that *can't* be represented by the basic multilingual plane of UTF-8, transliteration shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I think what you are doing with the double conversion is probably confusing matters, since you are saying convert to the encoding defined in the message from the detected encoding - which at best won't have any effect, and at worst will scramble the data if `mb_detect_encoding()` gets it wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks the problem got resolved with just mb_convert_encoding only. I had to use quoted_printable_decode before converting encoding that solved all the problems. Could you also let me know which method should be used mb_convert_encoding or iconv

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was staring me in the face.

But many of the examples on the web while correctly saying encode for UTF-8, the examples I saw either had escaping going on or incorrectly demonstrated how to do this for PEAR Mail function.

Here's the line I used that to define my headers that solved this for me.

```
$headers = array ( 
      'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
      'From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);
```

Hope that helps someone save the 2hours I just spend digging for this!